# exchangelib - traversing and accessing items in archive

Tags: python, archive, traversal, exchangelib

I've been trying to access folders and items in my Outlook archive using exchangelib. 
I can print out the tree structure in the account with `print(account.root.tree())` and iterate over the messages with:

```
for item in account.root.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:10]:
    print(item.subject, item.body, item.attachments)
```

..but how can I achieve the same in my archive?

`print(account.archive_msg_folder_root.tree())` does not return an equivalent tree-structure, and I cannot find a way to traverse the folder structure in my archive and access the messages' information in a given subfolder.

EDIT:

I should clarify. This is my folder structure in my outlook:
[The archive I am trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlaWM.gif)

I have my regular inbox and different folders, and an archive ("`Tilkoblet arkiv - <myuser@domain.no>`"), where items more than 3 months are moved to. I am trying to access these older items. Is `archive_msg_folder_root` the right way to go? Or do I need to change the primary_smtp_address?

Comment: `tree()` is supposed to print the tree at the level where `tree()` is called, but looking at the code again, there *may* be situations where the cached folder structure is not populated sufficiently. I'll have to add a test for that. You may have better luck accessing the subfolder using the `account.root / 'Some Folder Name' / 'MyArchive'` syntax. You can then `walk()` through all the subfolders in that folder.

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce this since my test account does not have an archive folder structure. I tried `recoverable_items_root` but it works without issues. What's the error or output you get from `account.archive_msg_folder_root.tree()` and what did you expect?

Comment: `print(account.archive_msg_folder_root.tree())` returns "Øverst i informasjonslageret", or "Top of Information Store" in English. I am suspecting the archive is not contained here?

Comment: Oh, that's surprising. Can you please open an issue on GitHub with this? The output of `account.root.tree()` and `account.archive_msg_folder_root.tree()` is necessary as a start.

Comment: Is `myuser@domain.no` the same as your primary account, or are the addresses different?

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/348)

Comment: Yes, they are the same.